# How can I specify which params to allow for a @ModelAttribute endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We have an endpoint like:

```
@Secured(Roles.USER)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value="/test",  method=RequestMethod.GET , produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody void test(@ModelAttribute BigCriteria criteria,
         @RequestParam(value="param1",required=false) String param1){           

    logger.debug(criteria.getParam1()); 
    logger.debug(criteria.getParam2());
}
```

Where BigCriteria is like:

```
public class BigCriteria{
  private String param1;
  private String param2;
  private String param3;
  ...
  //plus getters and setters
}
```

when calling /test?param1=ok output is: 
ok
null

when calling /test?param1=ok&param2=ok output is:
ok
ok  <--- We do not want this to be filled!!!

So, the question is:

How can we prevent @ModelAttribute to be filled only with params specified as @RequestParams?

Thanks

Comment: try to change the name of the RequestParam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestParam` parameters are set separately by spring MVC. So `@RequestParam(value="param1",required=false) String param1` only sets `String param1` if param1 is present in request but has no impact on `@ModelAttribute BigCriteria criteria`.

If you want to limit the parameters that are used to aliment `criteria` you should use an `InitBinder` annotated method to set the allowed fields for a defined ModelAttribute

```
@InitBinder("bigCriteria")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAllowedFields("param1");
}
...
@RequestMapping(value="/test",  method=RequestMethod.GET , produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody void test(@ModelAttribute("bigCriteria") BigCriteria criteria,
         @RequestParam(value="param1",required=false) String param1){           

    logger.debug(criteria.getParam1()); 
    logger.debug(criteria.getParam2());
}
```

I used a name on `ModelAttribute` to say that the `WebDataBinder` initialized above it to be used only for that `ModelAttribute`.

Comment: That's a great answer, do you know a way to allow only fields especified as query params?

Comment: Not sure to understand your last question. Where could they come from ?

Comment: Yeah, for instance: using setAllowedfields only those fields which I have annoted in that controller as a @RequestParam in order to do this automatically.

Comment: @ramon_salla I'm afraid it not the logic of Spring Framework. You'd better use it as Spring fellows want you to do ;-)